# Configuring EC2 instances for optimal performance and price?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've been using Amazons t1.micro servers for all my private web development projects so far, and it's been fine. Last week however I started to receive traffic to one of my websites, and the CPU instantly maxed out. The page is quite computation-heavy (uses one 5GB MySQL RDS), but it was like 30 simultaneous visitors and the t1.micro instance couldn't handle it...

I'm not very familiar with the different settings on AWS, so I just switched to a c1.medium instance which works fine for now. However it's quite expensive (in the long term), so my question is how to best configure the setup for optimal performance and price?

Almost all traffic is between 6 PM and 00 AM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWS Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) is the way to go.

It monitores the load on your EC2 instances and automatically boots up new instances, if the load gets too heavy. After the load is back at a normal level it will terminate instances, which are not needed anymore.